# readHTMLtable-error: arguments imply differing number of rows:

Tags: xml, r, screen-scraping, xlsx

I hope someone can assist me with the following problem. I have worked a bit with a developer for using a non documentet API for the danish webpage www.jobindsats.dk.

After a while I decided to go another way, simply to scrape the webpage.

So what I really want to do is to

```
#open packages
library(XML)
library(xlsx)

#Define an unsexy URL
url<-'http://www.jobindsats.dk/jobindsats/sv/DatabankViewer/ShowResult?mGroupIds=mgrpY25I10_1%2CmgrpY25I10_2&AreaType=_nykom&AreaSort=population&AreaIds=146&FrequencyId=m&PeriodIds=2009M01%2C2009M02%2C2009M03%2C2009M04%2C2009M05%2C2009M06%2C2009M07%2C2009M08%2C2009M09%2C2009M10%2C2009M11%2C2009M12%2C2010M01%2C2010M02%2C2010M03%2C2010M04%2C2010M05%2C2010M06%2C2010M07%2C2010M08%2C2010M09%2C2010M10%2C2010M11%2C2010M12%2C2011M01%2C2011M02%2C2011M03%2C2011M04%2C2011M05%2C2011M06%2C2011M07%2C2011M08%2C2011M09%2C2011M10%2C2011M11%2C2011M12%2C2012M01%2C2012M02%2C2012M03%2C2012M04%2C2012M05%2C2012M06%2C2012M07%2C2012M08%2C2012M09%2C2012M10%2C2012M11%2C2012M12%2C2013M01%2C2013M02%2C2013M03%2C2013M04%2C2013M05%2C2013M06%2C2013M07%2C2013M08%2C2013M09%2C2013M10%2C2013M11%2C2013M12%2C2014M01%2C2014M02%2C2014M03%2C2014M04%2C2014M05%2C2014M06%2C2014M07%2C2014M08%2C2014M09%2C2014M10%2C2014M11%2C2014M12%2C2015M01%2C2015M02%2C2015M03%2C2015M04&_sektor=300&BenefitGroupId=Y25&MeasurementId=Y25I10&Name=&CubeId=star_y25i10&HasPivot=False&RowAxis=_omrade%2C_omrade_f3b%2C_sektor%2C_periode&ColumnAxis=MeasurementAxis#step3'

#Write a table
write.xlsx(readHTMLTable(url,header=T,stringsAsFactors=F, encoding="UTF-8"),file='Numbers.xlsx')
```

I get the following error:

> Error in data.frame(`NULL` = NULL, `NULL` = list(V1 = c("Hele landet",  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 76, 1

The reason for that is (as far as I can see) that the first column is containing only one value 'Hele landet' ('the entire country').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the handy "Åbn i Excel" link that's on the page?

```
library(httr)

url <- "http://www.jobindsats.dk/jobindsats/sv/DatabankViewer/ExportToExcel?BenefitGroupId=Y25&MeasurementId=Y25I10&AreaType=_nykom&FrequencyId=m&CubeId=star_y25i10&AreaSort=population&HasPivot=False&MGroupIds=mgrpY25I10_1%2CmgrpY25I10_2&AreaIds=146&PeriodIds=2009M01%2C2009M02%2C2009M03%2C2009M04%2C2009M05%2C2009M06%2C2009M07%2C2009M08%2C2009M09%2C2009M10%2C2009M11%2C2009M12%2C2010M01%2C2010M02%2C2010M03%2C2010M04%2C2010M05%2C2010M06%2C2010M07%2C2010M08%2C2010M09%2C2010M10%2C2010M11%2C2010M12%2C2011M01%2C2011M02%2C2011M03%2C2011M04%2C2011M05%2C2011M06%2C2011M07%2C2011M08%2C2011M09%2C2011M10%2C2011M11%2C2011M12%2C2012M01%2C2012M02%2C2012M03%2C2012M04%2C2012M05%2C2012M06%2C2012M07%2C2012M08%2C2012M09%2C2012M10%2C2012M11%2C2012M12%2C2013M01%2C2013M02%2C2013M03%2C2013M04%2C2013M05%2C2013M06%2C2013M07%2C2013M08%2C2013M09%2C2013M10%2C2013M11%2C2013M12%2C2014M01%2C2014M02%2C2014M03%2C2014M04%2C2014M05%2C2014M06%2C2014M07%2C2014M08%2C2014M09%2C2014M10%2C2014M11%2C2014M12%2C2015M01%2C2015M02%2C2015M03%2C2015M04&_sektor=300&RowAxis=_omrade%2C_periode&ColumnAxis=MeasurementAxis&Name="

GET(url, write_disk("data.xlsx", overwrite=TRUE), progress(), verbose())
```

Comment: Wow. Amazing! Thanks.

It gives a lot of warnings? Is it something I should worry about? 
It gives this error 23 times.
1: In curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) :
  progress callback must return boolean

Comment: Try upgrading the packages and you can remove verbose in production